# How to load SVG to ImageView using Retrofit + Moshi?

Tags: android, svg, retrofit, moshi

Using Retrofit + Moshi how can I put SVG into ImageView.

Response from the server:

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="33" height="32" viewBox="0 0 33 32" fill="none"><ellipse cx="16.3233" cy="16" rx="16.2874" ry="16" fill="#E6F5F5" /></svg>`

Retrofit:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).asLenient())

@Headers("Content-Type: image/svg+xml")
    @GET("url/{id}")
    suspend fun getIcon(
        @Path("id") iconId: UUID
    ): Response<whatever>
```

Moshi setup:

```
private val moshi = Moshi
        .Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

Moshi error:

`com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path`

Is it possible with the given response ?

Comment: Add the whole exception and the model class in which you are deserialising your response.

Comment: This is whole message, and model is whatever, can be String

Answer (score 0):

The error message states it clearly that you specified type as Object (Response) but received String. I assume changing return type to String should work

```
@Headers("Content-Type: image/svg+xml")
    @GET("url/{id}")
    suspend fun getIcon(
        @Path("id") iconId: UUID
    ): Response<String>
```

or just

```
@Headers("Content-Type: image/svg+xml")
    @GET("url/{id}")
    suspend fun getIcon(
        @Path("id") iconId: UUID
    ): String
```